# I'm gettibg {"type":"UNAUTHORIZED","error_title":"Unauthorized"} while hitting post request of NEXMO

Tags: api, automation, vonage

In this i'm hitting NEXMO API for getting Reports

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class POSTRequest {
    @Test
    public void RegistrationSuccessful()
    {
        RestAssured.baseURI ="https://api.nexmo.com";
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();
// Sending Request Parameters
        JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
        requestParams.put("api_key", "xxxx"); // Cast
        requestParams.put("api_secret", "xxxx");
        requestParams.put("sig", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

//Sending Request Body
RequestSpecification APIBOdy =request.body("{\n" +
        "  \"product\": \"SMS\",\n" +
        "  \"start_date\": \"2019-10-26T00:00:00+0000\",\n" +
        "  \"end_date\": \"2019-10-27T00:00:00+0000\",\n" +
        "  \"sms_type\":\"MT\"\n" +
        "}")
.header("Content-Type","application/json");
        APIBOdy.contentType(ContentType.JSON);
        Response response = request.post("/v1/reports/");

//Printing Response on console
        System.out.println(response.getBody().asString());

//Checking Status Code
        int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
        Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, "201");
        String successCode = response.jsonPath().get("SuccessCode");
        Assert.assertEquals( "Correct Success code was returned", successCode, "OPERATION_SUCCESS");
    }
}
```

Response i'm getting:

{"type":"UNAUTHORIZED","error_title":"Unauthorized"}

java.lang.AssertionError: expected [201] but found [401]
Expected :201
Actual   :401

Even when I'm hitting the same request with the same body and params in Postman I'm getting accurate Response.

Comment: I think you have to use either Basic Auth or JWT as mentioned here: https://developer.nexmo.com/api/reports

.header("Authorization": "Authorization [base64(apikey:apisecret)]")

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use the v2 spec for your reports API needs as v1 is unsupported. This will require changes to your request body, and your means of authorization see: https://developer.nexmo.com/api/reports for full details

Some highlights in the spec that the api key / api secret are meant to be passed in via basic authorization in the header as a colon joined pair so your Authorization header will looks like:

```
Basic API_KEY:API_SECRET
```

you will need to convert the API_KEY:API_SECRET string to base 64 of course 
that can be done by extracting the byes from the string and using Convert.ToBase64String

```cs
var authBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(apiKey + ":" + apiSecret);
var authString = Convert.ToBase64String(authBytes)
```

Also you'll require product, accountId, and direction in your request body - and for the create report post request you won't need any query parameters.

In V1 I don't see any indication as to how you're generating your signature but you're meant to use either sig or your api secret not both. For more on signature generation see: https://developer.nexmo.com/concepts/guides/signing-messages

but realistically you shouldn't be using V1 anyway as it's not supported.

hope this helps!